# Wordpress is appending the plugin URL to the style property url()

Tags: css, wordpress, sass, wordpress-gutenberg, gutenberg-blocks

I'm making this gutenberg blocks plugin with a dozen of blocks.
One of them is giving me this weird behaviour.

Everywhere in the style.scss where there's a property with an anchor target, say, this one:

```
.mao1-d {
    mask: url(#mao1-c);
}
```

The browser is rendering as this:

```
.mao1-d {
    mask: url(/wp-content/plugins/cora-plugin-22/blocks/block15/build/#mao1-c);;
}
```

I have similar code within other blocks in the same plugin and that doesn't work.
The build .css is just like the .scss, without the plugin path:

```
.mao1-d {
    mask: url(#mao1-c);
}
```

Any ideas on how to solve this?

Comment: If you run `npm run lint:css` are there any errors in the console?

Comment: oh god yes, a huge list... what is this all? @S.Walsh

Comment: here's a glimpse:  
blocks/block1/src/editor.scss
 8:1  ✖  Expected no more than 2 empty lines   max-empty-lines

blocks/block1/src/style.scss
  9:2   ✖  Expected indentation of 0 tabs                     indentation                     
 10:5   ✖  Expected indentation of 1 tab                      indentation                     
 10:11  ✖  Expected "#ffffff" to be "#fff"                    color-hex-length

Comment: `lint:css` parses css and finds errors/issues. Most of them like 'no more than 2 empty lines' are not critical, but if you do have some issue thats causing the compiler to output the issue seen in your css, this should be able to help narrow down where the issue is.